# Building Jar For Custom UI Element JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I followed the steps of the following blog but cannot create a jar using netbeans whenever I am going to build a dialog box is coming like this

[image]

The blog which I have followed:

[Adding a Custom JavaFX Component to Scene Builder 2.0](https://rterp.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/adding-custom-javafx-component-to-scene-builder-2-0-part-2/)

The project contains following three files

i) FXML file
ii) Controller Class
iii) Style Sheet

Here is the tree view of the project:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that you miss a main class where you load your fxml and set and show the scene.
In NetBeans use Run/Build Project (F11) to compile and create a jar file.
Use Run/Run Project (F6) to compile and run your project. For this you need a main class.

The tutorial in the link works for me. I did the following:

- create project 'Stackoverflow' (the library)
- create project 'Stackoverflow2' (the main application using the library). 'Stackoverflow2' ist using library 'Stackoverflow' as you can see below the 'Libraries' node.

[image: NetBeans]

Content of file StackOverflow2.java:

```
package stackoverflow2;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StackOverflow2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("DemoScreen.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("stackoverflow");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Content of file DemoScreenController:

```
package stackoverflow2;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import stackoverflow.CommodityImageLabel;

public class DemoScreenController {

    @FXML
    protected CommodityImageLabel commodityLabel1;
}
```

Content of file DemoScreen.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import stackoverflow.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" 
            prefHeight="321.0" prefWidth="543.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" 
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="stackoverflow2.DemoScreenController">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="72.0" layoutY="34.0" text="Main App" />
      <Separator layoutX="24.0" layoutY="78.0" prefHeight="1.0" prefWidth="499.0" />
      <CommodityImageLabel layoutX="43.0" layoutY="98.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Content of StackOverflow.java:

```
package stackoverflow;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StackOverflow extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I didn't take care of the functionality - so the code is very basic.

Comment: When I am adding a main class in the above project then I can build it. But when I am going to import it in the scene builder it is showing a blank page. Can you please share the content of StackOverflow.java?

Comment: Have you tried to import this in Scene Builder? When I am going to do this it is showing me import dialog with zero items so I cannot import it.

Comment: I imported the jar file from my project StackOverflow. And yes it worked. You can download my two projects from my google drive. This is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxbJ93hsw2hkcC1HSGllV1FRdU0/view?usp=sharing